# How to get Maven to work with Python subprocess?

Tags: python, maven, subprocess

I am trying to write Python scripts to do some Maven commands automatically.

The following Python code does not work:

```
import subprocess
args = ['mvn', '-version']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

resulting in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

As a next step, I supply subprocess the full path to the `mvn` binary:

```
import subprocess
args = ['/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec/bin/mvn', '-version']
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
```

This command gets a bit further, but printing `err` reveals the following complaint:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/libexec/java_home/bin/java
```

As a sanity check, I verify on my own terminal that `JAVA_HOME` is correctly set:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T16:58:10-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

I am also able to run `mvn` without hassle on the terminal.

My question is: why is subprocess not able to run `mvn`, and how can I get it to do so?

Comment: Hmm ... It seems that the environment should be inherited from the caller.  Can you check the value of `os.environ['JAVA_HOME']`?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but for whatever reason, the JAVA_HOME implied in the error and the Java home from your "sanity check" seem to be different paths...

Comment: @mgilson `os.environ['JAVA_HOME']` was undefined, but by defining it explicitly in Python, the `mvn` subprocess call now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python inherits the environment from your terminal, and a subprocess spawned from Python should inherit the environment from the parent process. So I am not sure where the error regarding your JAVA_HOME env variable is coming from. Could it be that you do not spawn Python from the same terminal as you did the `mvn -version` test with?

Note that you can explicitly modify the environment for the child, via the `env` parameter to `Popen()`.

Comment: I have made subprocess scripts that run jars, and these have had no problem using `java` without explicitly defining the `env` parameter.   I am wondering what would cause this issue with `mvn`, as I am still using the full path to the binary.

Comment: I see that taking control of the environment helped resolving your issue. Since I proposed that you might want to give me an upvote at least ;-).

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
process = subprocess.Popen(args,shell=True)
```

Comment: this seems more appropriate as a comment

Comment: why is it not an accepted answer? That's all which is required.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue & spent almost an hour however it was easy to fix. Most of the people make mistake to use **mvn** rather **mvn.cmd** We must use **mvn.cmd** as mvn is window command application....

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['mvn.cmd' , '-version'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print(stdout, stderr)
```